# Control outbound connections in postfix

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I have a postfix server that i use to send auto responders and newsletters to subscribers.
I know that major ISP's like hotmail and yahoo look for how many connections they get from an ip address. SO i want to know the following
1. how many connection does a postfix server opens ?
2. how many emails per connection does a postfix server send ?
3. how can i control the amount of connections to a specific ISP ?

Thanks

Comment: You can get all the answers in www.postfix.org.

Comment: http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html

Answer (score 1):

> I know that major ISP's like hotmail and yahoo look for how many
>   connections they get from an ip address.

HOW do you know this ?
Experience by many professional mail admins shows that they throttle senders  solely based on the amount of mail they (try to) send in a given timeframe, *not* the amount of connections used.
One can still send 100 messages per second over one or two connections; the big ESPs will cut you off way before that point.

To answer your questions:

1. This is controlled by `default_destination_concurrency_limit`, which defaults to 20 connections per destination
2. Up to `max_use` messages will be sent over one connection, provided there are that many to send.
   For a single destination host, this will typically never be reached in one session.
3. This involves several steps: first, create a new transport for each destination, and set its $destination_default_concurrency_limit, and next, route traffic to these transport using transport_maps.

You can find a wealth of information concerning such setups if you search the postfix mailinglist for "yahoo slow transport"